# How to remove <!--nextpage--> tag from specific single page in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to remove `<!--nextpage-->` tag from my single.php content file, but it will show other single file like single-post1.php or single-post2.php. i tried with is_singular function, but when it enter in if condition it globally reset all contents, how can i do with it specific file.

```
add_action( 'the_post', function( $post )
{

 if(is_singular() && 'post' == get_post_type() && 'post1' != get_post_type() && 'post2' != get_post_type() ){

    if ( false !== strpos( $post->post_content, '<!--nextpage-->' ) ) 
    {
        // Reset the global $pages:
        $GLOBALS['pages']     = [ $post->post_content ];

        // Reset the global $numpages:
        $GLOBALS['numpages']  = 0;

       // Reset the global $multipage:
        $GLOBALS['multipage'] = false;
    }
}

}, 99 );
```

Thanks for your help....

Comment: Try look at: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/183582/how-to-ignore-or-disable-nextpage-tag

Comment: i have seen it, but there is not given solution for specific file